# How to use dictionaries with lists as value c# unity

Tags: c#

I am using a dictionary system to store my data and each thing I want to add to my dictionary will need to have 8 definitions. I want to know if anything like that is possible and if yes, I want to learn the codes for adding new items to the dictionary and read those items (if possible read the spesific things from the 8 items inside each list using index)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dictionary_matches : MonoBehaviour
{
    /*public static Dictionary<string, List<String>> Matches_dic = new Dictionary<string, List<String>>();
    dict.Add("key1", new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });*/


    public static Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    myDict.Add("Australia", "Canberra");
void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Don't post images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Matches_dic.Add("match 1", new List<string>());

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you are looking for something like this:

```
public class Dictionary_matches : MonoBehaviour {
  public static readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> Matches_dic = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() {
      {"match_1", new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c"}},
      {"match_2", new List<string>() {"abracadabra"}},
  };
  
  public void Update() {
    // You can use in any method of the class, e.g.
    Matches_dic.Add("more_match", new List<string>() {"p", "q"});
  }

  // Other staff
}
```

here we declare the dictionary and with two entries (`match_1` and `match_2`)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare such a dictionary its keys *and* values are empty.

Let's say I create one such dictionary

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
```

Now I want to add a value. But remember, my value is a `List<T>`.

So you need to check if your key is already present, and if it is already have an instanciated list as a value (e.g. a value != null)

```
if(myDict.ContainsKey("myKey") && myDict["myKey"] != null)
{
    // In this case you could do
    mydict["myKey"].Add("myValue");
    // Because you already have a list.
    // And to read the first item from the list
    var firstValue = mydict["myKey"][0]; // or using Linq replace [0] by First()
}

// Now if the key does not exist you need to add the key, and ideally an instantiated list.
if(!myDict.ContainsKey["myKey"])
{
    // In your case we know the expected length of the list, so let's specify it.
    myDict.Add("myKey", new List<string>(8))
}
```

You'll notice I didn't write the case where the key would exist, but the value is `null`.

I'll leave to your consideration if handling that particular case is needed, and if it is, you should have all necessary information in the example above.